# Translating French documents

Tags: 19th-century, birth-records, palaeography, france, translation

I need some help translating a couple of documents from 1800's France.  The first one is this birth record for Philippe Kindelberger.

[image: Scan of birth record]

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Before starting to translate your document, how far have you got with simply trying to transcribe it?  I think asking the community to both transcribe and translate a whole document makes your question insufficiently focused.  I think you should focus any similar questions on where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

What I was able to transcribe:

> Mairie d Thrie Derthiubau Arrondissement de Wissembourg Le trente Mai mil huit cent quarante-neuf, a six heure du foin
> Acte de naissance de Philippa Kindelberger ne a Niendenthinusbay Trenld Mai mil huit cent quarante-neuf a deux heure du sustin fil a de vereiniound age de ____ ans profession d ____ ne a ____ domicilie a _____ et de Elisabethe Kindelberger agee de ____ ans, domiciliee a ______
> L'enfant qui nous a ete presente, a ete recounu etre du sexe masculin

> Premier Temoin: George Neusiy age de soixante deux ans, profession de laboureur domicilie a Nieuerstisubay departement d aba Nyin

> Second Temoin: Jacque Walter age de trente six ans, profession de _____ deomicilie a ___ departement d _____

> Sur la declaration a nous faite par le ____ George age de soixante deux ain garde dennitenuline et apres lecture du present acte ont signe _____ Constate suivant la loi et dresse le present acte par nous Wingerter fromion Jolyn Maire, faisant les fonctions d'Officier de l'Etat civil, en presence et su la declaration des temoins ci-dessus denomares

> Le Maire,
> Wingerter

Which translates to something like (google translate):

> Mairie d Thrie Derthiubau Arrondissement of Wissembourg On the 30th of May, one thousand eight hundred and forty-nine, at six o'clock in the morning
> Birth certificate of Philippa Kindelberger was born in Niendenthinusbay Trenld May one thousand eight hundred and forty-nine at two o'clock in the afternoon of the sustin son of vereiniound age of ____ years profession of ____ born in ____ domiciled in _____ and of Elisabethe Kindelberger aged ____ years residing in ______
> The child who was presented to us was found to be male

> First Witness: George Neusiy, sixty-two years old, profession of plowman domiciled in Nieuerstisubay, department of aba Nyin

> Second Witness: Jacque Walter, thirty six years old, profession of _____ deomicilie in ___ department of _____

> On the declaration made to us by the ____ George age of sixty two ain garde dennitenuline and after reading this deed have signed _____ Acknowledges according to the law and draws up this deed by us Wingerter fromion Jolyn Maire, acting as Officer of the Civil status, in the presence and on the declaration of the witnesses above denomares

> The mayor,
> Wingerter